# SQL {setCharset} AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 1

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `{DB_TABLE_PREFIX}broadcast`;
#[QUERY]
CREATE TABLE `{DB_TABLE_PREFIX}broadcast` (
  `bid` mediumint(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `sortid` mediumint(8) NOT NULL default '0',
  `content` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `gourl` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '#',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`bid`)
) TYPE=MyISAM {setCharset} AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
#[QUERY]
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `{DB_TABLE_PREFIX}items`;
#[QUERY]
CREATE TABLE `{DB_TABLE_PREFIX}items` (
  `itemid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `uid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `account` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  `content` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `dateline` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `digg` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `reply` mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`itemid`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`)
) TYPE=MyISAM {setCharset} AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
#[QUERY]
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `{DB_TABLE_PREFIX}reply`;
#[QUERY]
CREATE TABLE `{DB_TABLE_PREFIX}reply` (
  `rid` mediumint(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `replyto` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `uid` mediumint(8) NOT NULL default '0',
  `account` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  `content` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `dateline` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`rid`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `replyto` (`replyto`)
) TYPE=MyISAM {setCharset} AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
#[QUERY]
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `{DB_TABLE_PREFIX}setting`;
#[QUERY]
CREATE TABLE `{DB_TABLE_PREFIX}setting` (
  `setname` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`setname`)
) TYPE=MyISAM {setCharset} ;
```

I try to import this to mysql database and receive this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '{setCharset} AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 1

Did I did miss something? Please help me out!

Comment: MySQL and/or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
TYPE=MyISAM
```

by

```
ENGINE=MYISAM
```

Try this, I have used table prefix as `"t_"`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t_broadcast`;
CREATE TABLE `t_broadcast` (
  `bid` MEDIUMINT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sortid` MEDIUMINT(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `content` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `gourl` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '#',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`bid`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t_items`;
CREATE TABLE `t_items` (
  `itemid` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `account` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `content` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dateline` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `digg` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reply` MEDIUMINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`itemid`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t_reply`;
CREATE TABLE `t_reply` (
  `rid` MEDIUMINT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `replyto` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uid` MEDIUMINT(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `account` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `content` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dateline` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`rid`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `replyto` (`replyto`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t_setting`;
CREATE TABLE `t_setting` (
  `setname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `data` TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`setname`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM ;
```

Comment: @EdmundYau - what value you set for {setCharset}

Comment: try replacing  TYPE=MyISAM {setCharset} ;        by      TYPE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

Comment: MySQL : Conflicting declarations: 'CHARACTER SET utf8' and 'CHARACTER SET latin1'

Comment: you can just use TYPE=MyISAM; remove the remaining part... actually I have executed one of the above query on my local machine and its working properly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `broadcast` (
  `bid` mediumint(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `sortid` mediumint(8) NOT NULL default '0',
  `content` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `gourl` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '#',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`bid`)
) TYPE=MyISAM  AUTO_INCREMENT=50 ;
```

The curly brackets were just for explanation as you refereed the syntax from some other source.